# Casting Object to LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper, linkedhashmap

I have parsed a json string using `ObjectMapper` into `Map<String, Object>`. Now while I am debugging this map, I see it's effectively a multi-level `LinkedHashMap`.

So, I would like to convert this `Map<String, Object>` to `Map<String, LinkedHashMap>` using `ObjectMapper`. I have tried the following:

```
Map<String, LinkedHashMap> tempJsonMap = mapper.readValue((JsonParser) originalJsonMap,
          new TypeReference<Map<String, LinkedHashMap>>(){});
```

Here in this above code, `originalJsonMap` is of type: `Map<String, Object>`.

But this code snippet is not working, I am getting error. In this context, I found a few examples to convert `LinkedHashMap` into a custom object but not the other way round.

Could anyone please help here?

Comment: Why you do not deserialise it to `new TypeReference<Map<String, LinkedHashMap>>(){}` when you deserialise `originalJsonMap`?

Comment: Hi, @MichałZiober thanks for your advice. Yeah, will do that.